# Сортировка Dictionary по Key в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c#, .net

Есть словарь `Dictionary<string, int>`,как можно отсортировать элементы словаря для вывода в консоль по Key в алфавитном порядке по возрастанию(от "a" до "z") без использования LINQ?
Как сделать через OrderBy я знаю

Comment: использовать алгоритм пузырьковой сортировки не пытались?

Comment: хотелось бы что-то менее громоздкое  
может через SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> можно?  
просто я пока не очень разбираюсь

Comment: У Dictionary элементы нельзя отсортировать.

Comment: отсортировать только для вывода, как orderby

Comment: [решение 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) [решение 2](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary)

Comment: это ответ с cyberforum. Его я видел.
Я же прошу разъяснить, как это работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и через `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, как вы заметили в комментариях. Согласно MSDN этот класс:

> Представляет коллекцию пар «ключ-значение», упорядоченных по ключу.

Таким образом, можно сделать так:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>() ...; // Ваш словарь

var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(dict);
foreach (var kvp in sortedDict)
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + kvp.Key + "; Value: " + kvp.Value);
// Или так:
//foreach (var key in sortedDict.Keys)
//    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key + "; Value: " + sortedDict[key]);
```

Если на входе:

```
["a"] = 10,
["z"] = 20,
["c"] = 30,
["m"] = 40,
["q"] = 50
```

Получаем вывод:

```
Key: a; Value: 10
Key: c; Value: 30
Key: m; Value: 40
Key: q; Value: 50
Key: z; Value: 20
```